# `for member in guild.members` stopped working one day

Tags: discord.py

I've been using `for member in guild.members` (or `ctx.guild.members`) since creatting my bot this spring and its worked no problem.  Then one day, it only lists the bot itself.

Did we get a new version of discord.py or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.py 1.5.0+ requires you to enable "Intents". In order to get a member list of a server, you will need to enable the server member intent in the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (Click your bot application, and go to the bot tab), take a look at this link: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents if you can't seem to find it. After you have done that, you need to do this in your code too.

For the code part, i think it's easier if you take a look at the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) yourself.